# 404 returned for WebAPI hosted on IIS6

Tags: ajax, iis-6, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We have already set up MVC4 on IIS6 , following the tutorial on Phil Haack's post: [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6 Walkthrough](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx).

Basically, we have:

1. inserted wildcard extension mapping to:
   `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll`
2. unchecked on Verify that file exists checkbox.

The pages can be loaded without a problem. But none of our ajax calls worked.

I always get a `404 Not Found`, no matter it is `POST` or `GET` or anything.

All my ApiControllers are located in `/Api/...`. `Build Action` is `Compile` and `Copy to Output Directory` is `Do not copy`.

Is there any other place I should look into?

Comment: Can you verify the urls your Ajax code is calling are correct?  What do they look like in the Network console on your browser?

Comment: Well, it works on the local machine using the IIS Express in Visual Studio.

Comment: So how are you creating the URL for the Ajax call?  Can you post the javascript?  It sounds like they are being created incorrectly, which would explain them working in Visual Studio, but not on the server.